Morpheme Tree Question
Is “International’s” in this sentence considered a noun?
I need to analyze that word and dissect it into different morphemes.
The sentence is

We value the International’s opinion.


It would appear to be a noun, since it using the possessive, and there is at least one newspaper called The International. A periodical's full name is often shortened to a single word, as with many other things.

@WeatherVane Might seem so, but no. The clitic represented orthographically by the grapheme <  's   > appends to the whole noun phrase "the International" not the noun "International". So, in actual fact "International's" isn't even a constituent! Consider "The woman you met secretly's husband"

@Araucaria noun or noun phrase, is still a noun.

the International's opinion = the opinion of the International. Regardless of what the International actually means...

@Araucaria-Him That view of "-'s" as a clitic is fairly controversial, no? CGEL, at least, gives a long argument against it.

@alphabet Yes, quite controversial. In CamGEL almost every word class can inflect for the genitive, including adjectives, prepositions, infinitival makers, verbs and so forth. That overweirds me out. However, even if one takes that view, it's still problematic for Weathervane's argument that International's is a noun because it has a possessive 'ending' or, as they put it, "is using the possessive".

If "The International" is the name of the paper, "The" should be capitalized.

@Araucaria-Him Why is it problematic? It's either a possessive or a contraction for "is", and the latter doesn't make sense in this sentence.

@Barmar In The man you spoke to's sister the word to's is genitively inflected, but it is not a noun and thus  Weather Vane's theory that if the word is 'possessive' it is a noun is fatally flawed.

What about "the international"?  Doesn't the article, or the article together with the possessive marker, make clear that it is something capable of having an opinion, an entity?  Or when doing your morphemic analysis do you have to ignore everything else, as if such an analysis alone could answer the question?

The capitalization of I indicates that this is a proper noun, so it's a noun.
If it weren't capitalized, it would be a nominalized adjective, an adjective that's being used as a noun (e.g. "the rich", meaning rich people). "international" is not a common nominalized adjective like that example, but the example sentence could be used in a context where opinions are being offered by both natives and a a visitor from abroad; "the international" would refer to the visitor.

This doesn't really answer the question, which is about how to draw a morphological tree for the word (and about its classification as a single syntactic unit--see the issues raised in the comments).

I don't know what a morphological tree is. I was answering the question "Is it a noun?"

It depends on whose grammatical dogma you follow. This is my take:

I see the genitive as expressing a prepositional phrase -> of the International".


That's a syntax tree of the sentence, not a morpheme tree of the word.

You're right - it only answers the first part - I have amended.
